# Start and End Dayof a selected date

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I am trying to get the start and end day of a selected day. I have used moment-timezone.js but I am only getting the start and end of today using this

```
start = moment().tz('America/New_York').startOf('day').unix();
end = moment().tz('American/New_York').endOf('day').unix();
```

I dont know how to get the start and end of a given date, such as 01/03/2018 
I have tried this

```
start = moment().tz('01/03/2018','MM/DD/YYYY','American/New_York').startOf('day');
```

but it gave me this error:

> Moment Timezone has no data for 01/03/2018. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.

Comment: Use `America/New_York`, not `American/New_York`

Comment: yeah. my typo, I used America/New_York.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Moment Timezone docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/), the correct usage is:

```
start = moment.tz('01/03/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'America/New_York').startOf('day');
```

Comment: Ah, got it. I have moment().tz that's why it doesnt work. Thanks